# Ausearch won't convert files

Tags: linux, bash

I have a lot of auditd files that I need to interpret and convert to csv. I have been trying to use this simple bash script but it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(find . -name '*.log')

for file in $files 
do  
      touch ${file}.csv
      ausearch -if "$file" --format csv>> "${file}.csv"
done
```

It finds the first file fine, but it doesn't convert the file, nor does a file get created with the `touch` command.

Comment: Those are pretty grave syntax errors; are you sure you posted your actual script? This should fail with a syntax error for the missing single quote, and would definitely not find the first file (it should simply skip the loop entriely since `files` is empty).

Comment: For the record, the syntax to assign the output of a command to a variable is `files=$(find . -name '*.log')` with no spaces allowed on either side of the equals sign; but capturing the output in a variable is superfluous if you just want to loop over it. Probably try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: You have asked a few questions in the past but not accepted any of the answers provided. Are answers on StackOverflow not helping you?

Comment: I was trying to copy the first part from memory (the script is on an isolated system). The actual script does have the variable properly created. As for my other posts, they do help, I just didn't know I had to do something to accept an answer besides upvoting (I have only begun using stack overflow recently and I am not an expert in that). My main issue is not with instantiating the variable, but with the ausearch

Comment: Please [edit] to provide the actual code you want to ask about. Transcription errors distract from the real problem, and can sometimes cause your question to be closed as unclear, unreproducible, or outright off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing all this in a oneliner (not tested)?

```
find ./ -name "*.log" -exec ausearch -if {} --format csv >>{}.csv \;
```

It's the same as the command you provided, but `$file` is replaced by `{}` (result of the `find` command).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. This worked! The only problem is that the name came out as {}.csv instead of the previous file plus .csv. Do you know how to get that to output?

Comment: You're welcome, but I don't know how to help the name of the output file: `{}` is the normal use for parameter substitution in UNIX/Linux and it can be used different time, so I have no idea what's causing this. However, I believe that, asking this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ might give you a quick answer.

Comment: You can't interpolate `{}` twice, try `-exec sh -c 'for f; do ausearch -if "$f" --format csv >>"$f.csv"; done' _ {} +`